# asp.net mvc 3, Themes (different Views)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add themes to my site that will use totally different Views. I want to see them in my project like this:

```
Views/Theme1/...
Views/Theme2/...
```

instead of default

```
Views/...
```

And of coz I need a simple way to switch between them.

So the question is: how can I make ViewEngine to look for Views in a specific place mentioned, for example, in web.config?

**Added**

Solved the base problem with this, thx to Archil:

```
public class ThemedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public ThemedRazorViewEngine(string themeName)
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/" + themeName + "/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/" + themeName + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml" };
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/" + themeName + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml" };
    }
}
```

Everything good, but "right click - > go to view" doesn't work any more (side effect, no big deal).

And now I came up with another question: on web site we have administration panel that should be theme independent ofc. How can I fix that? to have something like this:

```
Views/Admin/...
Views/Theme1/...
Views/Theme2/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution for theme value in web.config is to create custom ViewEngine and override only view search locations. This way you dont have to change anything in Controller (Example uses only cshtml files for c# only view engine, you have to add vbhtml extensions if you want to use visual basic views)

```
public class ThemedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public ThemedRazorViewEngine(string themeName)
    {
        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/ " + themeName + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/" + themeName + "/{0}.cshtml" };

        //and same for all of below
        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" };
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
    }
}
```

And registration of view engine

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ThemedRazorViewEngine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["currentTheme"]));
```

Comment: thx, it worked. had to fix `_ViewStart` files also. What are these Areas? It works without changing them. And is it possible to make "right click - > go to view" work with this solution?

Comment: @Wonder if this helped you, you should consider marking it as answer. take a look at this link for areas - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee671793.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> how can I make ViewEngine to look for Views in a specific place
>   mentioned.

You need to give the path in the View method:

```
return View("~/Views/Theme1/Index");
return View("~/Views/Theme2/Index");
```

And for the `web.config` example:

```
var themeFromWebConfig = GetThemeFromWebConfig();
var viewName = "~/Views/" + themeFromWebConfig + "/Index";
return View(viewName);
```

Comment: thats the first thing came to my mind, but it doesn't look like the clearest solution. i don't whant to add this to every View, i'm looking for a specific place where i can mention it once.

Comment: @Wonder. You can write your own `ViewEngine` Good Luck with it... **=)**

Comment: yeah, seems what I need is some help with making  `public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine`

Comment: If the problem is the path of your views. Before writing your own viewengine's extension, you could try and create a controllerBase that expose ViewPath properties or somthing similar.

Comment: @gdoron, btw, `return View("~/Views/Theme1/Index");` doesnt work