# Look for MVC Views in other locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have three web projects on Asp.net MVC3:

Portal.Web -> Common controllers and models

Portal.WebsiteCustom -> Custom website 1

Portal.WebsiteCustom2 -> Custom website 2

Both custom sites uses the controllers and models of Portal.Web.

Now i would like to add the common views on this project and set MVC to look on Portal.Web project for common views.

Is this possible?

How i could archieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own view engine that implements `IViewEngine`, it has a method that looks for where to search views. You could also extend the `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` and override the locations to add custom file locations to find views.

Sample code for such a thing is located in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9063559/16587).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Yes.

> How i could archieve this?

You will have to embed those views as resources into the assembly and then reference the assembly in your client MVC project. Next you will have to write a custom virtual path provider that is able to retrieve those views as embedded resources instead of looking for them in the current project folder which is the default process.

You could use the [`Razor Generator package`](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) which allows you to [`simplify the process`](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/documentation) as it already provides you with the custom virtual provider that you don't need to manually write. And here's an [outdated article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) that you could also check.